# Is it possible to transfer OpenVZ VPS image to XEN platform?

Tags: virtualization, vps, xen, xenserver, openvz

I'm having a memory related issue with my vps on openvz platform and I guess that my hosting provider is overselling RAM. So, I'm thinking to move on a xen platform since ram cannot be oversold but I don't want to re-configure everything from the beginning. Is it possible to take an image of my current vps running on openvz and extract it on a xen platform? This is not for developing or testing, it will be for production use.

All suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS is this? If linux you could do an rsync over.

Answer (score 1):

Quick short answer more to encourage research but give you the idea:

exclude.txt

```
/boot
/proc
/sys
/tmp
/dev
/var/lock
/etc/fstab
/etc/mdadm.conf
/etc/mtab
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/conf.d/net
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/networks
/etc/sysconfig/network*
/etc/sysconfig/hwconf
/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables-config
/etc/sysconfig/kernel
/etc/hostname
/etc/HOSTNAME
/etc/hosts
/etc/modprobe*
/etc/modules
/etc/udev
/net
/lib/modules
/etc/rc.conf
```

--

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 30000' -azPx --delete-after --exclude-from="/home/demo/exclude.txt" / root@1.2.3.4:/
```

You basically are just cloning from one server to another.

Do some trial runs first. This is just a copy and paste from my local saved notes. ;)